# Menu option Insert -> Script... is missing in my Spreadsheet, how do I fix it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've two documents: in the first one I was able to add 'Script...' (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/286530/87805)) from the Insert menu, but in the second one and all new which I'm creating I don't have this option present.

Why is this option is missing, and how I can activate this option or what do I need to do?

Comment: In both the old and the new Google Sheets, the script editor can be found under _Tools>Script editor_. If you're planning on adding a script, then that's the place to be.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is your `1st one` is the old Google Sheets and your `2nd one` is new Google Sheets, where the Script gallery has been moved to Add-ons and renamed Add-on store.

This is the answer to the question of which this has been deemed a duplicate:

> The Scripts Gallery menu item will not appear in new spreadsheets if you have opted in to the new Google sheets (@Vidar S. Ramdal).

Answer (score 9):

Now it has been moved to Extensions > Apps Scripts

Answer (score 6):

If the Tools --> Script Editor and the Add-ons menu options are missing when you open the file, it probably isn't actually a Google Sheets file.
Make sure to navigate to File --> Save As Google Sheets.

Then the Script Editor option in the Tools menu and the Add-ons menu will be available.